# How do we calculate the derivative of the inverse of a matrix?

Tags: derivatives, approximation

When I was reading Chapter 10 of [B&V's Convex Optimization book](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/), I encountered a first-order approximation on Page 554,
$$\tag{1}
(X+\Delta X_{nt})^{-1}\approx X^{-1}-X^{-1}\Delta X_{nt} X^{-1}
$$
As we know that the first-order approximation is $f(x+\Delta x)\approx f(x)+Df(x)\Delta x$ in the derivative form or $f(x+\Delta x)\approx f(x)+\nabla f(x)^T\Delta x$ in the gradient form. I tried to figure out the second term on the RHS, but I failed. I found a formula in Matrix Cookbook as follows.

$$\tag{2}
\frac{\partial Y^{-1}}{\partial x}=-Y^{-1}\frac{\partial Y}{\partial x}Y^{-1}
$$
But $X$ is a matrix in (1), not a scalar. I get more confused when I recalled that taking a derivative on a matrix w.r.t another matrix will result in a bigger matrix built in a form of Kronecker product, e.g., $\nabla_X(AXB)=B\otimes A^T$. So, I think that (2) is not helpful for deriving (1).

Any instruction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(X):=X^{-1}$. Starting with $$X\cdot f(X)=I$$
and differentiating both sides gives $$\Delta X\cdot f(X)+X\cdot Df(X)(\Delta X)=0.$$
Therefore $$Df(X)(\Delta X)=-X^{-1}\cdot\Delta X\cdot f(X)=-X^{-1}\cdot\Delta X\cdot X^{-1}.$$

Comment: Your answer is helpful. Can I think of your equation as $dX\cdot f(X) + X\cdot Df(X)dX =0$? BTW, a typo $f(X)$ is supposed to be defined as $X^{-1}$.

Comment: @suineg yes $dX$ is also appropriate to denote infinitesimals (perhaps more than $\Delta X$). Thanks for spotting the typo.